# Making specific text bold in a string in C# Windows Forms

Tags: c#, colors, textbox, formatting, richtextbox

I want to make part of the text bold in a textbox, for example the textbox contains.

"This is a text box"

So it will be "This **is** a text box"

How can I do it in C# Windows Forms?

Comment: So is it that only second word should be bold?

Comment: Try using html This '<b>is</b>' a text book

Comment: It's windows forms by the way, and not necessarily second, Robert - word of my choice.

Comment: Is this a RichTextBox or just a normal TextBox?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the help of `FontStyle` interface.
Just add a button in your form and name it Bold and create a click event for that.
You have to use `RichTextBox` for this, you cannot do this with `TextBox`.
This code will convert the selected text to bold.

```
private void btnBold_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FontStyle style = tbMessage.SelectionFont.Style;
        if (tbMessage.SelectionFont.Bold)
        {
            style = style & ~FontStyle.Bold;
            btnBold.Font = new Font(btnBold.Font, FontStyle.Regular);
        }
        else
        {
            style = style | FontStyle.Bold;
            btnBold.Font = new Font(btnBold.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
        }
        tbMessage.SelectionFont = new Font(tbMessage.SelectionFont, style);
        tbMessage.Focus();

    }
```

Comment: What if I want just a word from the message?

Comment: select that word with the help of mouse and click on the bold button which has the event handler with code above. This will make the selected word Bold/Unbold. Just try this code once , you will understand.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it in a standard TextBox control, you need to use a RichTextBox control with appropriate formatting.

Answer (score 0):

To be clear, you cannot do that in a `TextBox`. Use a `RichTextBox`.

In a `RichTextBox`, start by selecting the desired text by setting the `SelectionStart` and the `SelectionLength` properties or let the user select text interactively. Then apply a formatting by setting one of the `Selection...` properties:

```
richTextBox1.Text = "This is a text box";
richTextBox1.SelectionStart = 5;
richTextBox1.SelectionLength = 2;
richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font(richTextBox1.SelectionFont, FontStyle.Bold);
```